# Get Aadhar details using android finger scan api?

Tags: android, android-fingerprint-api, aadhaar

Currently, I am using Adhar API for getting Adhar details. but for that, I need "Secugen device" for scan finger.

but As Android 6.0 introduced finger sensor so I want to use that so I can avoid Secugen device for finger scan.

Is it possible to fetch Adhar details using Android finger scan SDK?  or is there any other way to implement this?